# Issue AngularJS nested transclusions and isolate scope

Tags: angularjs-directive

I've come across an issue with isolate directives and nested transclusions and hopefully some can enlighten me as to what's going on.

In a nutshell, I have two directives, each with its own isolate scope

- a with a template `<div b><div ng-transclude></div></div>`
- b with this template `<div><div ng-transclude></div><div>`.

When I use

- `<div a>{{greeting}}</div>`  then the greeting doesn't show
- `<div a>{{somePrivatePropertyOfA>></div>` then I can see the property of the isolate scope.

If directive's scope is not isolated, then the private property does not leak through and the greeting is shown.

I've created a [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sh3uOy5cZzT8wtS0wRgI) that illustrates in more detail what I'm trying to do. It also shows that the private property of the isolated scope leaks through to the template.

I think this issue can be solved in my particular case by writing my own compile function, but I'd like to understand **why the transcluded content ends up being bound to or inheriting from the  isolate scope of directive a**.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old so you probably found the answer but I'm still going to try to explain it as other people might find it useful.

There are three things to remember when working with isolated scopes and transcluding content with `ng-transclude`directive.

1. Isolated scope means that it doesn't inherit properties of its parent. It only inherits properties that you explicitly bind inside the scope object.
2. Transcluded content gets compiled and linked only after it's inserted.
3. `ng-transclude` creates a new sibling scope of the directive which transcludes the content. Although, this may change from version 1.3.0 [ng-transclude should not create new sibling scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5489).

The best way to understand what's going on in your example is to look at your scope tree.

```
< Scope (002) : ng-app
    < Scope (003) ng-controller
        < Scope (004) : b
        < Scope (005) : ng-transclude <--- Content rendered under this scope
        < Scope (006) : aIsolated
            < Scope (007) : b
            < Scope (008) : ng-transclude
                < Scope (009) : ng-transclude <--- Content rendered under this scope
        < Scope (00A) : aNotIsolated
            < Scope (00B) : b
            < Scope (00C) : ng-transclude
                < Scope (00D) : ng-transclude <--- Content rendered under this scope
```

In your first example Angular finds the `b` directive. It rips out the content, creates an isolated scope and compiles its template. When compiling the template it finds the `ng-transclude` directive. It creates a new sibling scope and inserts the content into it. Since `ng-transclude`'s scope is a sibling, its parent is an `ng-controller`. Therefore, the content inherits all the properties of your `MainCtrl` controller.

In the second example, Angular finds the `aIsolated` directive. It rips out the content, creates an isolated scope and compiles its template. When compiling the template it finds the `b` directive and starts compiling `b`. It rips out the content wrapped by the `b` directive, creates an isolated child scope for `b` and compiles the template. When compiling the `b` template it finds the `ng-transclude` directive. It creates a new sibling scope and inserts the content into it. I.e. this new sibling scope is passed to a `transclude` function which makes the content a child of the `ng-transclude` scope. Then it starts compiling the content where it finds another `ng-transclude` directive so it creates a new scope and inserts the content with `{{message}}` and `{{private}}` expressions into it. Finally it gets to compiling and linking the expressions. But if you look at the inheritance tree you will find that the content inherits properties of `aIsolated` scope, which brings us to isolated scopes.

`aIsolated` directive has an isolated scope so it cannot access `private` property defined in the parent scope so the content reads the property you defined in `aIsolated` controller. Directive `b` then creates an isolated scope as well and adds a `private` property to it but because it's isolated it's not overriding its parent's property. Therefore, when all directives finish compiling and linking, the properties that are defined in the `aIsolated` directive are put into `{{message}}` and `{{private}}` expressions. `message` property doesn't exist so it's empty.

The compilation process of the third example is exactly the same as in the second one. It only differs by the `aNotIsolated` directive which simply creates its own scope thus inheriting properties defined in `MainCtrl` controller.

> If directive's scope is not isolated, then the private property does
>   not leak through and the greeting is shown.

That's not entirely true. The reason it may appear this way is because `aNotIsolated` does not define its own `private` property. Here in [my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5agRHPC5OQO5iyzAJxg) `aNotIsolated` defines `private` property in its controller so you can see the private message is different to your example.

Also leaking is not a good word to describe what's happening. Expressions are evaluated under the scope where they were inserted into. So `{{message}}` and `{{private}}` expressions are evaluated under `ng-transclude` scopes which in turn inherit either from the `MainCtrl`, `aIsolated` or `aNotIsolated` scopes.